# Portable Class Library in NuGet Package .Net 4.0.3

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package

My Portable Class Library targets .Net 4.0.3 and higher + SL5 (4.0.3 required for `System.Xml.Linq`). We are okay with requiring that users have .Net 4.0.3. I can take the resulting DLL and reference it in a project that targets .Net Framework 4 just fine. When I `nuget spec` the project file, `pack` and then try to add the reference through NuGet, it gives the following error:

"You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework"

How can I change my NuGet package to allow the same DLL to work with 4.0?

Comment: I modified the package with the NuGet Package Explorer, changed `lib/portable-net403+sl50` to `lib/portable-net40+sl50` and it worked. I guess I need to find a way to make the `pack` command do this.

Answer (score 0):

When you pack , are you creating the correct subfolders before you pack ?

```
.\NugetPackageBase\content\           (.png files, xdt files, etc)
.\NugetPackageBase\lib\net20        
.\NugetPackageBase\lib\net35
.\NugetPackageBase\lib\net40
```

You can quick check it by:

```
Making a copy of your ".nupkg" file.
Change the ".nupkg" extension to ".zip"
```

And now you can look inside and see the directory structure.

Comment: I'm referencing the project file when I pack, it is handling the structure creation. Does this mean I need to manually set up the nuspec file to pack into the right folders?

Answer (score 0):

you can manually edit the .nuspec file before running nuget.exe pack command, if you want to change the target framework.

Comment: do you mean by specifying a file and target?